# Query for records within time range using UTC and time zones

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, utc, datetimeoffset

I am looking for a solution to quickly and efficiently search for records using start and stop times that are inclusve of the current system time. My hope is that I can find a solution that doesn't require that SQL Server to perform mathmatics or conversion on the format of the data that is stored in the tables. Accounting for daylight savings time can be done using a second set of values and the query logic can determine prior to execution if US daylight savings rules are in effect. My intent is to use UTC for the current time so the logic could move to Azure or other data centers and be location agnostic.

Solutions I've considered but found reasons they fall short:

- Storing integer based offsets from UTC in hourly or minute increments. As time ranges cross the 24 hour mark, I can't perform a between operation like this: @CURRENT_HOUR BETWEEN 16 AND 4.
- Storing only time based strings (ex: 09:00 & 18:00). These values have to be converted to a date time value to be compared to another date time value.

The current solution in use calculates the current time for each record using UTC offset and that is requiring a lot more work of SQL Server than should be required for this operation.

The best solution I've found so to use a DATETIMEOFFSET format, setting the values to a unified 1900-01-01 format so that the records are date agnostic, and only the current system time has to be adjusted accordingly.

DATA

```
ZIP    CITY         ST  START_OFFSET            STOP_OFFSET             START_OFFSET_DST        STOP_OFFSET_DST
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10001  New York     NY  1900-01-01 09:00 -5:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -5:00  1900-01-01 09:00 -4:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -4:00
60601  Chicago      IL  1900-01-01 09:00 -6:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -6:00  1900-01-01 09:00 -5:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -5:00
80202  Denver       CO  1900-01-01 09:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 09:00 -6:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -6:00
85001  Phoenix      AZ  1900-01-01 09:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 09:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -7:00
90001  Los Angeles  CA  1900-01-01 09:00 -8:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -8:00  1900-01-01 09:00 -7:00  1900-01-01 18:00 -7:00
```

QUERY

```
-- Get the current UTC date/time and adjust it to be 1900-01-01 with the current time and offset
DECLARE @UTC_TIME AS DATETIMEOFFSET = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+00:00'), '1900-01-01')) * 1, SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+00:00'))
SELECT  @UTC_TIME -- EXAMPLE: 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000000 +00:00

SELECT  TimeZoneId
FROM    dbo.TimeZones
WHERE   @UTC_TIME BETWEEN START_OFFSET AND STOP_OFFSET -- Ignoring DST logic for this example
```

The issue with this approach is once UTC rolls over 23:59, the date/time in the example will be 1900-01-01 00:00:00 instead of 1900-01-02 00:00:00 and won't fall between the intended range values when they are compared. I'm hoping someone will help me spot the forest for the trees on calculating a better offset or offer a new approach for the data structure that will still allow the query to avoid calculations.

This logic needs to run on SQL Server 2008 and I do not want to implement CLR to solve it.

Edit:
The purpose of this data query is determine reasonable call times for B2B marketing across US zones. We mostly use zip codes with their offsetting time zones and fall back to states if we don't have zip code data for the prospect. Our data is 99% US based, with a few records in Guam, Puerto Rico, etc. If a record gives a false positive its not the end of the world but we do try and restrict our marketing phone calls to 9A to 6P local time for these prospects.

If I wasn't clear before, I am looking for a way to track a time range only, not a date range on these records.

Comment: You don't make it clear what time zone you're storing data in, but I would always store the data in UTC time (and run the server in UTC as well). It is much easier to deal with singleton conversions from local time to UTC at insert / update time than to deal with all of the data at query time. For reporting queries you simply adjust the parameter values instead of all the data. You need some kind of calendar-based rule for conversion from local time, though, since some time zones observe DST on different dates and some regions don't observe it at all.

Comment: Search [this page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/49/aaron-bertrand/) for "time zones" without the quotes; I wrote a three-part article on this topic that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, but I don't think those blogs cover what I need. I am fairly certain I landed on your posts a couple times in my previous research on this issue.

I'm looking specifically for time based determination, not date/time. If I store the UTC time, local + offset, some records will have > 24 hour ending period causing them to roll over. I can't use current UTC time between 14 AND 02, the math doesn't work out. I have considered doing a +24 to low values, but I can't resolve a solid way of doing that.

Comment: But you can’t just convert times between UTC and some local time zone without also knowing the date, unless you’re ok with being an hour off sometimes, or you only deal with time zones that don’t observe DST.

Comment: Using zip code data I know which areas observe DST and intend to pre-calculate the [ECMP]ST and [ECMP]DT time ranges for those records. For zones that don't observe DST the time ranges will be the same in both columns. When the logic executes I determine if US DST is in effect in a single call, then use that value to determine which sets of columns I need to compare. I am not concerned with other forms of DST for non-US locations.

Comment: Regardless of what you’ve already figured out and what you’ll figure out later, the crux of your problem seems to be that you want to search all rows for data you don’t know you’re looking for until runtime. If you have to apply time conversions to data that’s stored in order to figure out which of those rows match your filter after that runtime calculation, there is no magic efficient way to do that. Again this is why I’m suggesting you standardize how you’re storing the data and adjust the goal posts in your where clause, vs. trying to adjust all of the data to see what fits between posts.

Comment: I definitely appreciate your help on this @AaronBertrand. Reading back through the thread, I believe I haven't been clear on this => I want to store the time values in UTC so that no pre-processing will need to be done before a row's values can be compared. I plan to do any adjustments necessary to my query values prior to running the SELECT so that SQL can quickly compare the adjusted value against the row stored ranges. Storing the start and stop times are reasonably simple, but I haven't found a reliable way of handling the 24 hour rollover.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172917/discussion-between-chris-porter-and-aaron-bertrand).